# How can I proxy ICMP requests?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, proxy, icmp

I have a ubuntu server that receives many ping requests from various other servers in the network. I would like to be able to proxy these requests.  Using iptable rules I can see how to DROP or ACCEPT the requests but is there a way to redirect them?  More specifically I'm looking for a way to conditionally respond to them.  Maybe a little psudo code will help explain...

```
 if [ "$SourceIP" ==  "192.168.1.5" ]; then
    #send response
 elif [ "$SourceIP" == "192.168.1.6" ]; then
    #drop
 elif [ "$SourceIP == "192.168.1.7" ]; then
    sleep 20
    #send response
 fi
```

I know I can use iptable rules to drop and accept for specific ip addresses (the first two scenarios).  But I need more control than that.  I need to be able to put logic into when and if a response is given.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any ideas you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

As you have already realised, iptables can perform certain actions (drop/reject/accept) on certain conditions (IP/port/protocol/etc). You can have your iptables file organised in a similar way as to what you just described in your shell script example.

I think you can either operate on iptables/netfilter extensions/modules as to define actions for given scenarios (Rejects on certain IPs, accepts on others etc.), writing them in specific order (like in your shell script). I am not sure what exact actions you want to perform and at what conditions, but you may try checking for extensions here:
[Netfilter Extensions HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO.html) as well as [XTables-Addons](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/)

There was also a discussion on severfault how to introduce extra delays with `tc`, if you need those in place as well.